# Why don't I have a Restart option? Why did restart disappear (not show up on power options) on 20.04?

Tags: shutdown, restart

I just installed a few things and some updates.
i went to restart my computer Ubuntu 20.04 but I don't have the [Restart] option.
Has this been removed?  Or has something else occurred?

[image: power options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, after you click the Power Off... option, you will see the choice in a popup window.

[image: power option choices]

Comment: This useability issue is corrected in later versions: all options now simply appear under the Power Off/Log Out menu item.

Comment: @vanadium Good to know. I thought maybe it appeared on the main menu before (16.04) but I couldn't remember and I genuinely thought the option was entirely gone at first.  thanks